# PJAX with Laravel getting error notice on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, pjax

I've got pjax working fine in most instances, but when submitting a form, I'm getting an odd error message in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined`

I've tracked this down to line 123 in pjax.js, which is:

```
 function handleSubmit(event, container, options) {
    options = optionsFor(container, options)

    var form = event.currentTarget

    if (form.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'FORM') //error occurs here
        throw "$.pjax.submit requires a form element"

    var defaults = {
        type: form.method.toUpperCase(),
        url: form.action,
        container: $(form).attr('data-pjax'),
        target: form
    }
```

The code still seems to fire correctly, but I'd like to clean up the errors.

So, I added a `console.log(form)` just before that to see what was happening, and here's what I got:

```
undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined
<form method="POST" ...
```

Looks like it must be firing the method `handleSubmit()` twice, once with blank data and once with the form, but I can't figure out why. Here's where I fire pjax:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-pjax]', function(event) {
  $.pjax.submit(event, '#pjax-body');
})
```

EDIT: here's what my form looks like (using blade)

```
{!! Form::open( ['url'=>['users/changestatus'], 'data-pjax']) !!}
{!! csrf_field() !!}
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $user->id}}">
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="{{ $user->status }}">
<button type="submit" >Update</i></button>
{!! Form::close() !!}:
```

Comment: problem with your `var form` because it doesn't contain any value.

Comment: the form being submitted isn't empty. have added the form to the question for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I was submitting the form twice: once through the button, and once through some ajax I'd setup before refactoring for use with pjax. Basically comes down to a stupid oversight